# How to set icon for c++ application window and icon for task bar?

Tags: c++, windows, icons

How to set these icons for application?
I am using visual studio.
[image]
[image]
The icon on application window is empty.
I have already added a project.rc file to project and have added icon resource into it
And it shows the correct icon on the task bar when I dock it to the task bar.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've found 2 methods of doing this after a quick search, assuming you are dealing the the WIN32 API in some form. This is by no measure a complete list of available methods.

1.Set the `hIcon` member of the `WNDCLASSEX` structure used to register your main window to an appropriate value like the following code does. (Where `EXAMPLE_ICON` is your icon resource)

```
WNDCLASSEX wcex = {}; 
wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(EXAMPLE_ICON));
wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
wcex.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
wcex.lpszClassName = "ExampleIconWindowClass";
wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APPLICATION));
```

2.You can send a `WM_SETICON` message to your main window like the following (Again, where EXAMPLE_ICON is your icon resource)

```
HICON hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(EXAMPLE_ICON));
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_SMALL, (LPARAM)hIcon);
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)hIcon);
```

Here is the end result of either of these methods:
[image: Finished Product]

Sorry about the poor formatting, I'm still unfamiliar with this website.