# C++ Windows Title image

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a text based game with visual studio and c++. For design purposes I used SetConsoleTitle to change the title, but I was wondering if it is possible to also change the picture/image at the top left of the window title bar. Can someone help me out?

I looked on the internet but could not find anything about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set icon for c++ application window and icon for task bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45727291/how-to-set-icon-for-c-application-window-and-icon-for-task-bar)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try [GetConsoleWindow function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolewindow), then send a message  [WM_SETICON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-seticon)